# set_new_handler and errno

Tags: c++, memory, errno

If you use `set_new_handler` and your handler function is called, is `errno` guaranteed to be set, the way it is on a return of 0 from `malloc`? Or is it better to use `strerror(ENOMEM)`? `errno` works on Microsoft C++ and GCC, but that still leaves the question of whether it's guaranteed.

Comment: It depends a lot on the implementation of the standard library. Generally `errno` is only valid directly after a failed system function, and if you don't know what calls are made in the system `new` function there is no way of knowing if `errno` is valid or not.

Comment: Note that ENOMEM is not defined in standard C or standard C++. So the answer will not be found in the C++ standard, this more like a Posix/Windows question. [Edit: I'm somewhat wrong, ENOMEM is in C++11, but the standard doesn't mention it other than in a list of errno values]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `errno` is good enough for detecting dynamic memory allocation failures. Looking at N3337, specifically *3.7.4.1 Allocation functions*:

> **2** [...] Even if the size of the space requested is zero, the request can fail.
>   If the request succeeds, the value returned shall be a non-null pointer value (4.10) p0 different from any
>   previously returned value p1, unless that value p1 was subsequently passed to an operator delete. The
>   effect of dereferencing a pointer returned as a request for zero size is undefined.<sup>35</sup>
>
> **3** An allocation function that fails to allocate storage can invoke the
>   currently installed new-handler function (18.6.2.3), if any. [ Note: A
>   program-supplied allocation function can obtain the address of the
>   currently installed new_handler using the std::get_new_handler
>   function (18.6.2.4). —end note ] If an allocation function declared
>   with a non-throwing exception-specification (15.4) fails to allocate
>   storage, it shall return a null pointer. Any other allocation function
>   that fails to allocate storage shall indicate failure only by throwing
>   an exception of a type that would match a handler (15.3) of type
>   std::bad_alloc (18.6.2.1).

and footnote 35 (this is only a indicative and non-normative):

> <sup>35)</sup> The intent is to have operator new() implementable by calling std::malloc() or std::calloc(), so the rules are substantially
>   the same. C++ differs from C in requiring a zero request to return a non-null pointer.

Now, heading on to the C standard draft, N1570 and a look at *7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`*:

> **3** The value of errno in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of
>   errno in other threads is an indeterminate value), but is never set to zero by any library
>   function.202) The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call
>   whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the
>   description of the function in this International Standard.

It appears that `errno` may be set by a `malloc` failure but this is not required.

Also *7.22.3 Memory management functions* from the N1570 does not specify that `malloc` or friends are required to set `errno`.

My suggestion would be to stick to what the standard guarantees and use the exception (`std::bad_alloc`) thrown by `new` (i.e. not use the no-throw `new`).

Answer (score 2):

There's no requirement that `new` (or `malloc`, for that matter) set `errno`.  Both have a clearly defined error reporting semantics (throwing `std::bad_alloc` or returning a null pointer) which doesn't involve `errno`.  (From a quality of implementation point of view, I would not want `new` or `malloc` to be allowed to modify `errno`.  Non obstante the Posix requirements.)